# FireMonkey - Distributing Win32 application

Tags: windows, deployment, inno-setup, firemonkey

I have developed a `Win32` `FireMonkey` app using `IBLite` embedded database manager. I want to distribute it to other `Win32` environments, using `Inno Setup`. I have configured the `Deployment` info on `Tools > Options` according with `Port` number and `IP address` suggested by `AP-server`, set the `password` to `masterkey`, tested the connection (which is OK) and make the `Deploy`. Next, on `Inno setup`, on `Files` section, I included all generated files and set `DestDir = "{app}\DestPath"`, where `DestPath` is the same as in the output dir of the generated `Deploy` dir. Then I built the script and run the installation file. Every thing is OK on `Program Files (x86)\MyApp`: all files where correctly copied at their respective directories. Nevertheless the app stacks, because can not get access to the database (I know this is true, because I did the whole process without database access and the main app screen was correctly displayed). The database itself, is placed on `C:\Users\Public\Documents`.

My environment:

```
OS       - Windows 10 64 bits (updated)
IDE      - Rad Studio 10 Rio (version 20)
app kind - FireMonkey
```

What I am missing?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your post that you describe deploying the database. If it's not in your installation, it won't be on the machine where your app is installed.

Comment: Also, if you are in fact deploying the database, and you're putting it in `{app}\DestPath`, it would have to be read-only, because normal non-administrator users can't write to the `{app}` folders. This has been the situation since Windows Vista was released.

Comment: @Ken. I have updated the question, regarding the database.

Comment: Well. Now I wonder if PA Server must be running in the host machine. Is that so?

Comment: No. Why would PA Server have to be running in order to use a database on Win32? Can you be more specific about the problem than *(can not get access to the database*? You'll need to do some basic troubleshooting here, because we don't have access to either your source code or the application where you're trying to install.